# Using hidden frame to store or pass data between pages

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We need to implement a mechanism to persist information between web pages in the same session. There is a lot of information on the client-side and passing it back and forth to the server across requests is something we want to avoid. HTML5 local storage is one option.

The other option mentioned was "using a hidden frame where the data is kept".  I am not sure what this option really means.

- Does it mean keeping a hidden frame that holds on to the data across page requests?
- How would this be accomplished? Are there any jquery plugins or sample code I can look at?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way where you can keep data in the main page and use a hidden `iframe`/`frame` to persist data. This is because once the main page is reloaded (when you go to another page), everything in the iframe is lost.

You would basically use the main page as your data-storage location. On top of the main page, you would superimpose an `iframe`. The user would interact with your site through the `iframe`. From the user's perspective, there is no difference. You can persist information by writing to the parent frame (the main page). Since the main page is never getting reloaded, you can persist data inside it.

I am not aware of any Javascript libraries that do this; I will take a look though.

Keep in mind that this might affect SEO and possibly navigation (not back/forward buttons). Another point, as Guffa noted, is that users cannot share links to your page since the URL in the address bar never changes (all interaction is via the `iframe`). So when your user sends someone a link, they will end up at the very first page.

Comment: There *is* one difference from the user's perspective. The URL in the location bar doesn't change, so it doesn't reflect what you see. If you try to use the URL to share a page with someone, they will end up at the starting page instead.

Comment: @Guffa Good point. I was thinking about the same thing when I wrote about SEO, but forgot to add it! Will edit.

Comment: For simplicity's sake, let us assume that it is a secure app and users cannot share links to the page, without possibly saving the state to the server.

Comment: @Thimmayya Then you can use the method that I've described (that is, if the caveats that I've described are not a concern).

Comment: The OP said *...keeping a **hidden** frame...*. If the `iframe` is the one the user interacts with, it can not be hidden. Or does this refer to the actual page being hidden? Or might there be another technique that really uses a hidden frame (although I cannot imagine how does would work)?

Comment: @Felix I took some creative liberty but assuming that we could think of the page as the main frame :) But in all honesty, I don't think it can be done any other way. Even if you keep a hidden iframe, once you reload its content/hit another URL, the iframe disappears. You might be able to persist data in the querystring, but that doesn't seem to elegant and it prone to being exploited. I will update my answer to highlight this point.

Comment: Thanks Felix for clarifying further.. The "hidden frame"option was mentioned to me by someone and I am trying to make sense of the option. I believe he was talking about "hidden iframe" and the user is not interacting with this iframe.
@Vivin - persisting data in the querystring is not an option because of the large amount of data. Btw, thanks for the lively discussion.

Comment: @Thimmayya Maybe you can ask him to explain further? I don't know how data can be persisted in a hidden iframe if the main page is going to be reloaded.

Comment: As I said I cannot imagine a way with a hidden (i)frame either (otherwise I would post an answer :D). I was just wondering about the "hidden". There is also the possibility that this other person either expressed or understood it wrongly...

Comment: [Clarified with the original suggester] : 

each page would consist of two frames, the main content frame and another frame which isn't visible (width=height=0).
when you navigate to a new page only the content frame changes - the hidden frame stays resident.
The hidden frame's javascript is where all the data is stored. 

- [so that looks fairly straight-forward. I will go ahead and accept Vivin's answer, as it seems to be a reasonable solution to what I asked (though not exactly what the original suggester was talking about)].

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep a frame from one page to another, so the only way to use that is to make the frame cover the window and load the actual pages in the frame. That way you can keep the data in the surrounding page that won't be replaced.

This of course means that you actually never leave the page. The URL in the location bar remains the same when the content changes, so you can't bookmark a specific page or share it with others. Search engines will link to the content pages instead of the frame, so anyone finding your page that way will end up on a non-functioning frame page.